# Validation loss falls but train loss remains constant?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, validation

My validation loss (left) falls to near 0, while my training loss (right) remains basically unchanged (gradient step is on the abscissa). This is the opposite of the typical error in which train loss falls, but validation loss remains constant. Does anyone know what might cause this?

[image]

Edit: Added plot from another run with log scaling:

[image]

Comment: Can you recreate the graphs with the same y scale, maybe excluding the first 100 steps? Hard to tell if there is actually a problem since the scale on the train graph is a few orders of magnitude below the scale on the left.

Comment: Added another plot with y log-scaled. Hope that helps!

Comment: I discovered that the difference in train and eval loss magnitudes is caused by setting `model.eval()` during evaluation and `model.train()` during train. I don't know exactly why this makes a difference

Comment: Are you using dropout, batch norm, or other methods with non-deterministic behavior?

Comment: Yes, batch norm and dropout

Comment: `model.eval()` turns off dropout and batch norm.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that doesn't explain *why* this phenomenon occurs

Comment: You don't know why turning off dropout would change the predictions of the model?

Comment: No. I don't know why turning off dropout during validation would result in a validation loss that falls with more gradient steps *without also reducing the training loss*.

Comment: Or why turning off dropout makes the validation loss 3 orders of magnitude larger than the training loss.

Comment: It's not clear from your comments exactly how you're training the model, and what behaviors correspond to which modes of loss measurement (with/without dropout & batch norm). Can you [edit] your post to explain (1) which measurements are taken with `model.train()` or `model.eval()` (2) what the unexpected behavior is? The second set of plots appear to show values that are very similar, but slightly higher for validation, except for a transient spike in the training data. This doesn't seem at all unusual.